# How do I disable the textboxes that is within a loop?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I don't know how to properly reference my codes to disable the text with the checkbox.

```
<form method='POST'>
<?php

$index = 0 ; 
while($index <= 4){
    echo "<input class='click' type='text' data-text='test$index' id='text$index' value='text$index' disabled>test$index</input><br>";
    echo "<input type='checkbox' id='test$index' >test$index</input><br><br>";
    $index++;
}

?>
</form>
```

above i have a looped checkboxes and textboxes

and below is my  jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    $('#'+id).change(function(){
        var disable = $(this).attr('data-text');
        if(('#'+disable).prop('checked')){
            $('#'+disable).removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        else{
            $('#'+disable).attr('disabled');
        }   
    });

});
```

below is the live demo via stack snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.click').change(function() {
    var disable = $(this).attr('data-text');
    if (('#' + disable).prop('checked')) {
      $('#' + disable).prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
      $('#' + disable).prop('disabled', true);
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<form method='POST'>
  <input class='click' type='text' data-text='test0' id='text0' value='text0' disabled>test0</input>
  <br>
  <input type='checkbox' id='test0'>test0</input>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input class='click' type='text' data-text='test1' id='text1' value='text1' disabled>test1</input>
  <br>
  <input type='checkbox' id='test1'>test1</input>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input class='click' type='text' data-text='test2' id='text2' value='text2' disabled>test2</input>
  <br>
  <input type='checkbox' id='test2'>test2</input>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input class='click' type='text' data-text='test3' id='text3' value='text3' disabled>test3</input>
  <br>
  <input type='checkbox' id='test3'>test3</input>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input class='click' type='text' data-text='test4' id='text4' value='text4' disabled>test4</input>
  <br>
  <input type='checkbox' id='test4'>test4</input>
  <br>
  <br>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't see any attribute `'data-menu'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Try this :  I Hope I have solved your problem , here is the complete code

```
</html>
<form method='POST'>
<?php
$index = 0 ; 
while($index <= 4){
    echo "<input  type='text'  id='text$index' value='text$index' >test$index</input><br>";
    echo "<input  class='click'  id='test$index' data-text='$index' type='checkbox'  >test$index</input><br><br>";
    $index++;
}
?>
</form>
</html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.click').click(function(){
    var disable = $(this).attr('data-text');
 if ("#"+disable.change ){
       $("#text"+disable).attr("disabled",  $(this).is(':checked')); 
        }
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'm sorry placed the wrong title but your code could work with couple of tweaks. I entitled the question **How do I disable the textboxes that is within a loop?** instead of **How do to remove disabled from textboxes that is within a loop on checked?** thanks though

Comment: just refreshed the page because i was trying to tweak you code. this if else worked for me :) thanks a lot 
`if ("#"+disable.change){
       $("#text"+disable).prop("disabled",  !$(this).is(':checked')); 
    }
    else{
     $("#text"+disable).prop("disabled",  $(this).is(':checked')); 
    }`

Answer (score 1):

According to the [HTML 4 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Your element ID seems to be number here:

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' id='test$index' >
```

Also, as @charlietfl pointed out, your ID is duplicated as it is the value for both your text inputs and your checkboxes here:

```
echo "<input class='click' type='text' data-text='test$index' id='text$index' value='text$index' disabled>test$index</input><br>";
echo "<input type='checkbox' id='test$index' >test$index</input><br><br>";
```

The following selector is not finding your input:

```
$('#'+disable).prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: what's wrong with `prop('disabled', boolean)` ? Your answer doesn't provide any reason your code should work where OP code doesn't

Comment: @Mikey attributes and properties of elements are not the same thing

Comment: That's true, just fixed my answer. Must likely his problem is with his selector / element ID.

Comment: ID can begin with number in html5 ... bigger issue is duplicate ID

Comment: @charlietfl true! Thanks for correcting me.
chemical_elii What doctype are you using?

Comment: I'm using `<!doctype html>`

Comment: @chemical_elii I have just updated my answer to reflect what charlietfl said might be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler approach without using ID and using prev() and a simple boolean toggle for based on `checked`

```
$(':checkbox').change(function(){
   $(this).prev().prop('disabled', this.checked);      
});
```

Comment: I don't see duplicate ID's . Are you pertaining to `data-text='test$index'` and `id='test$index'`? because my ID for text box is `id='text$index'`. I have used this kinda similar code like this before for manipulating `.toggle()` on div's. And I'm just trying to convert it so i can use it in a looped inputs

Comment: ahhh I did misread and missed the difference between `test` and `text`. Create a simple demo with some live html

Comment: I'm sorry, I am very new to this forum thing. how do I create a demo?

Comment: Lots of sandbox sites you can use like jsfiddle.net, jsbin.com, codepen.io, plnkr.co as well as `stack snippets` right in the question

Comment: I tried both stack snippets and jsfiddle.net but none runs php script in their live demo :(

Comment: no...you need to copy some html source from page or manually create the thml